# How to get browser language in ServiceWorker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

How to get browser language in ServiceWorker?

```
navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; //not work
```

Answer (score 8):

This should work now [according to the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#the-workerglobalscope-common-interface).

If your users are using an older version of Chrome, you have to rely on the language read from the global (regular) `window.navigator.language` and [pass it to the Service Worker via `navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage`](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/post-message/). Here is the old [Chrome tracking bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=276159).

Alternatively, you can try reading [`Accept-Language` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) from your Requests in `fetch` event handler - `event.request.headers.get('Accept-Language')` - although it didn't work for me for some reason.